# Constant values supplied from properties files in UiBinder GWT

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I have constant values supplied from properties files

**MyConstants.java**

```
    public interface MyConstants extends ConstantsWithLookup {
        public String text();
    }
```

**MyConstants.properties**

```
    text=Hello!
```

To get the text I do the following

```
    private MyConstants constants = GWT.create(MyConstants.class);
    Button button=new Button(constants.text());
```

I'd like to know how to create button with text provided from properties files using UiBinder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">

    <g:HTMLPanel>
            <g:Button>Hello!</g:Button>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

And also I have fieldset tag, how to add text to its legend

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
        <fieldset class="panel">
            <legend>Hello!</legend>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look on [Using an external resource](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Using_an_external_resource)

---

Try in the same way as we are doing for `CssResource` to inject into `ui.xml`.

Sample code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">

    <ui:with type="com.x.y.z.client.MyConstants" field="c">
    </ui:with>

    <g:HTMLPanel>
            <g:Button text="{c.text}"/>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

---

**EDIT**

Use [CaptionPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/CaptionPanel.html) instead of `fieldset`

```
 <gwt:CaptionPanel captionText="{c.text}"></gwt:CaptionPanel>
```

Comment: you are perfectly right, but can you help me with `<fieldset>` tag, which I added in my edited question

Comment: I opened your link and found how to add text resources
`<legend><ui:text from='{c.text}'/></legend>`. Thank you so much for your help!)